# twisted matrix framework for java

Tags: java, twisted

is there a twisted matrix framework for java??

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675093/twisted-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) could be one.

Answer (score 0):

While the very original version of twisted was written in Java, and there are a few implementations of Deferreds and a simple reactor written in Java, they aren't in a published library state.

Searching for an alternative you might do well to google with various keywords such as "asynchronous networking library" and such.