# Suggestions For Java Event-Loop Libraries

Tags: java, event-loop

I am looking for something like the JavaScript `setTimeout`, but with a `Runnable`, with the following restrictions:

- Does not require individual dedicated threads per timeout.
- Already developed and thought through.
- Maybe even including additional features. (cancel timeout?, wait for something?, async I/O?)
- Does not require any GUI libraries. (Java FX/Swing/AWT all have event loops built in)

Do you have any suggestions?

Edit: I have found what I am looking for. A plus would be if there was a library that also included something related to either non-blocking or asynchronous I/O.

Comment: I think it's called "XNIO" or "Mina". More async-IO based, and not as general as Twisted/POE (?), but otherwise what is asked for. (I wonder if there *is* a Java replacement for Twisted/POE?)

Comment: Oh, with the right terms: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675093/twisted-in-java a response recommends Mina. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033271/can-twisted-be-implemented-in-java

Comment: Interesting, not directly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743008/should-all-event-driven-frameworks-be-single-threaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) :

- you decide how many threads are used
- standard JDK class
- cancellable tasks
- not related to any GUI

I don't really understand the link between scheduled runnables and an event loop, but maybe you'll find what you're looking with this class.

Comment: There would probably be a thread that waits until the scheduled time arrives, an event loop would do that, and more. Does that clarify?

Comment: It is too old to answer, [ReactiveX](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) project built under the hood of Netflix. A library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs by using observable sequences.

Answer (score 2):

You can use java.util.Timer

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

You can set the task run only once or periodically. 
You can also stop/cancel individual TimerTask or all tasks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a simple node.js style event loop in Java, [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) is a good start.

Take a look at the [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) factory mentioned in the javadoc for [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), particularly [Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29). This gives you a single background thread (like the Node event loop: see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493996/everything-runs-in-parallel-except-your-code-wait-what)) to which you can submit tasks.

For async IO, tasks handling blocking activity need to split of a Thread (or Executor) and use a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to submit the result back to the event loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think Vert.x is what you need, it is event driven and non blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using  awaitTermination API of [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

```
tpe.awaitTermination(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

might be useful to you.